# Chrome extension mv3 refused to load the script

Tags: google-chrome-extension, azure-cognitive-services, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am trying to create an extension that can use Azure cognitive service sdk to make speech to text. Everything worked fine with the mv2 extension but since i have to migrate to mv3 i'm having some trouble.
Step by step i'm trying to make it all works. Now i'm stuck with an error

*Refused to load the script 'blob:chrome-extension://extension_id/{...}' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback*

I'm having this issue since i'm trying to implement the Azure sdk in my web accessible resources which is an iframe to make all the retranscription.
I saw that some people are talking about a bug, some that we can't use external script.

Here is my code

**audiosources.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <script src="distrib/browser/microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech.sdk.bundle.js"></script>
        <script src="audiosources.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**audiosources.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message, sender, sendResponse) => {
    switch(message.type) {
        case "startStreaming":
            startStreaming(message, sender, sendResponse);
            break;
        case "init":
            console.log("init");
            break;
    }
    sendResponse();
});

function startStreaming(message, sender, sendResponse) {
    for (const tabId in Live) {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(parseInt(tabId), {
            type: "removeTranscript",
        });
        stopStreaming(tabId);
    }
    captureUser(sender.tab.id);
}

function captureUser(tabId) { 
    audioConfigUser = SpeechSDK.AudioConfig.fromMicrophoneInput(microphoneId);
    recognizerUser = new SpeechSDK.SpeechRecognizer(
        speechConfig,
        audioConfigUser
    );
    console.log("recognizerUser : ", recognizerUser);
    recognizerUser.startContinuousRecognitionAsync();
    recognizerUser.recognized = (s, e) => {
        toContentUser(tabId, e.result.text);
    };
}
```

the error occurs when i use the function

> startContinuousRecognitionAsync()

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "version": "1",
    "name": "Extension stt Azure MV3",
    "minimum_chrome_version" : "93",
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
            "js": ["content.js",
                    "public/js/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"],
            "css": ["public/css/index.css"]

        }
    ],
    "background": {
        "service_worker" : "background.js"
    },
    "web_accessible_resources": [
        {
            "resources":["audiosources.html", "public/icons/copy_icon_24dp.png", "public/css/index.css"],
            "matches":["<all_urls>"],
            "use_dynamic_url": true
        }
    ],
    "permissions":["tabCapture", "tabs"],
    "action":{
        "default_popup":"popup.html",
        "default_icon" : "./public/icons/logo.png"
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: ManifestV3 disallows dynamically generated code. Try asking the authors of that SDK library how to implement it without using a blob: URL. I guess it's used for a worker, in which case they may have a version with a standalone worker script or they may write it in order to support ManifestV3.

Comment: Yeah i asked explained the same problem in their github repo, i hope for an answer. But i don't get it why it is not working with this file when i tried to make another one and it worked. I have my sdk in my project shouldn't it work ?

Answer (score -1):

This is purely security issue with the chrome extensions. This is general error. In manifest.js do some modifications. As the static data binding is trusted already, dynamic allocation of external sources need to be whilisted.

Change in manifest.js file

```
{
  "name": "example",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "example extension",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://*/*"],
      "run_at": "document_start",
      "js": ["inject.js"]
    }
  ],
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    {
      "resources": [ "myscript.js" ],
      "matches": [ "https://*/*" ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Check the below in config file

```
Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, OPTIONS"
Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000;"
Content-Security-Policy "script-src 'self'"
X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"
X-Frame-Options "DENY"
-Server
```

[Reference](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/147554/security-headers-for-a-web-api)

Comment: What do you mean by config file ? and my manifest.json file seems the same as yours no ?

Comment: In general, we will be having manifest.js file to manipulate JS file and settings. If the name is different in your case, kindly, check the main settings page from your code blocks.